# Add space after each fourth + sign

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have such a text for example:

"A01+B02+C03+D04+E05+F06+G07+H08+I09+J10+K11+L12+M13+N14+O15+P16"

I would like to add a space after each fourth '+' sign.

This is because if the text is too long in the grid's cell in my page, then it's simply cut off. So I'm thinking to simply wrap the string before binding the data to the grid.

I've played around with several string methods, like getting the IndexOf and the adding a space with Insert, or using a StringBuilder to make a completely new string out of the original one, but I just can't get the final solution running.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Keep a count of the number of + signs you pass.  When you reach the fourth one, add a space, zero the counter, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Is your string always this format?  If so, the solution is simpler and doesn't require you to scan for the + sign.

Comment: I have considered using a counter but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Make sure you do a call like this: myStr = myStr.Insert(index, " "); In the very beginning of my C# career I missed the fact that Insert does not modify the original string, only returns the modified string separately.

Comment: @Kendrick: in theory it should be always in this format, 3 characters and then a + sign. But I wouldn't like to rely completely on that assumption. That's why I want to use the + sign, which is 100% sure.

Comment: Is this a web page or a windows form?  Not enough tags!

Comment: @ Josh Stodola: it's a web page, sorry about the lack of tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
string input = "A01+B02+C03+D04+E05+F06+G07+H08+I09+J10+K11+L12+M13+N14+O15+P16";

string final = string.Join(
    "+", 
    input
        .Split('+')
        .Select( (s, i) => (i>0 && i%4==0) ? " "+ s : s));
```

Comment: I decided to use the LINQ approach. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 10):

Use a regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^+]*\\+){4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.replaceAll("\1 ");
```

Comment: "but then he'll have two problems" (I keed I keed) (or do I?)

Comment: @drachenstern: The two problems thing only refers to when you don't know how to craft the right regex. If you're a regex pro and you don't care about performance, then regexes are not a "second problem". It's that simple.

Comment: @Platinum Azure ~ the guy asking the question is NOT a regex pro, and doesn't even know that a regex will solve the problem, since he didn't ask if a regex was the right way to go. Sod off or give me constructive feedback. I was telling @thejh with as few words as possible that he's giving the guy a second problem (learning and using regex) when solving the first one. Cos the guy will try and use and get it wrong to use a regex next time. Then he'll have three problems. (not being able to support existing code)

Comment: The question is for C# and this answer is in Java :P

Comment: @drachenstern: My, we're touchy today. I wasn't saying that you were wrong in this case because you are completely right (and maybe I should have emphasized that, so please accept my apologies). I'm saying that asserting anyone who uses regex will have two problems is false and unfair and it irritates me how people use that quote as a buzzword sometimes. Yes, it looked like you were just spouting a buzzword at first, but I can see now that you can actually back it up. I'm not sure telling me to "sod off" was remotely called for, though, and I'm not sure I appreciate that.

Comment: @Callum: Ooops... err... um... well, I think that I didn't read the question carefully enough...

Comment: @Platinum Azure ~ Yes, I've been told thrice now that I'm touchy today, so my apologies. You're quite right.

Comment: And if this answer makes the OP want to learn regexes, then it's definitely the best answer.

Comment: @Platinum Azure~ No, just wanted to defend my position more fully. Took the wrong road doing so.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use the [CSS word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap) property to break the string at a certain width...

```
td.longString {
  max-width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Just set `CssClass="longString"` to the column in question.

Comment: +1 for data preservation, and fixing the real issue; the display of the data.

Answer (score 3):

Easier:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"((?:[\w_]+\+){4})", "$1 ");
```

Comment: +1, fixed your replacement pattern syntax to use `$1` and used verbatim string with `@` symbol to escape pattern properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = "A01+B02+C03+D04+E05+F06+G07+H08+I09+J10+K11+L12+M13+N14+O15+P16";
string[] parts = test.Split( '+' );

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder( );
for( int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++ )
{
    if( i%4 == 0 )
    {
        output.Append( " " );
    }
    output.Append( parts[ i ] + "+" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the first what comes to my mind. Not the most beautiful though.

```
var str = "A01+B02+C03+D04+E05+F06+G07+H08+I09+J10+K11+L12+M13+N14+O15+P16";
        var strings = str.Split(new [] {'+'});
        var builder = new StringBuilder(strings[0]);
        for(var i = 1;  i< strings.Length;i++)
        {
            builder.Append(i%4 == 0 ? "+ " : "+");
            builder.Append(strings[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are all well and good but as someone once said

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

What about this simple solution isntead:

```
    String testString = "A01+B02+C03+D04+E05+F06+G07+H08+I09+J10+K11+L12+M13+N14+O15+P16";
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(testString);

    int plusCount = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<buffer.length(); i++) {
        if (buffer.charAt(i) == '+')  {
            plusCount++;
            if (plusCount == 4) {
                buffer.insert(i+1, ' ');
                i++;
                plusCount=0;
            }
        }
    }
```